# Is this output only strange because of heuristics?

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm currently programming a tool to find a path with a set amount of stops. For that I'm using [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/3256) answer. But when trying the code with the below data, a very strange path is generated:
[image: Path that is not optimal]

As easily seen in the image, this is by far the most optimal path, even between just the visible points.
And so I was wondering whether this is just a problem of heuristics, or if there is anything wrong with my code (Note: The path starts and ends at a given point, in the image that is the leftmost point):

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from typing import List
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
import gpxpy
import gpxpy.gpx
from gpxpy.gpx import GPXWaypoint

START_LOCATION = GPXWaypoint(38.892743662408584, -77.03258470988436, name="Start")

def createOutputGpxRouteFile(stations:List):
    output = gpxpy.gpx.GPX()
    gpx_track = gpxpy.gpx.GPXTrack()
    output.tracks.append(gpx_track)
    gpx_segment = gpxpy.gpx.GPXTrackSegment()
    gpx_track.segments.append(gpx_segment)
    for station in stations:
        gpx_segment.points.append(gpxpy.gpx.GPXTrackPoint(latitude=station.latitude, longitude=station.longitude, name=station.name))
    print('Created GPX:', output.to_xml())

def readGpxData():
    """Reads the gpx data from a file and returns a list of the coordinates"""
    # Original code commented so it is reproducible
    #with open("Waypoints.gpx", "r") as gpx_file:
    #    gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)
    #gpx.waypoints.insert(0, START_LOCATION)
    waypoints = [
        GPXWaypoint(38.91965, -76.99145, name='GC7J4FJ', description='Cache Store by Shalacknar (2/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.90755, -76.989483,  name='GC7CYPZ', description='West Virginia Ave.: The 50 States Project by UrbanAdventureSquad (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.9242, -77.008083,  name='GC7R9Z9', description='Stronghold neighborhood by mellow_cello (2/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.89614, -76.97886,  name='GC9XVTY', description='Take Something, Leave Something by DCSunshine11 (1/1)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.91295, -77.000967, name='GC7FC8C', description='DC Hidden Murals #30: 28 Blocks by exmachina (2/1)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.921817, -77.011167,  name='GC7JHBD', description='Catlandia by mellow_cello (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.9037, -76.992583, name='GC78CZD', description='Florida Ave.: The 50 States Project by UrbanAdventureSquad (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.9, -76.988753,  name='GC3PBQ2', description='DC Hidden Murals #17: Dusk of H Street by exmachina (2/1)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.901917, -76.99155, name='GC9AYCF', description='A DC Saint? by poli1136 (1/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.916983, -77.007967,  name='GC7R8YH', description='Rhode Island Ave.: The 50 States Project by UrbanAdventureSquad (2/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.895096, -76.985681,  name='GC9GBFY', description='Triangles and Tribulations by urbnX (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.917633, -77.010833,  name='GC7KD9P', description='Bloomingdale: Crispus Attucks Park by mellow_cello (2/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.934617, -77.028583, name='GC4KRFJ', description='I thought he made elevators by zdonb & lilbru (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.891967, -76.985233, name='GC9WRM2', description='Meet me at the crossroads by urbnX (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.88075, -76.97475, name='GC6RP1W', description="Doug's Cache by puglisimclare (1,5/1,5)"),
        GPXWaypoint(38.907475, -77.003103,  name='GC8AT5F', description='SideTracked - NoMa-Gallaudet U Station by mellow_cello (2/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.896342, -76.992444,  name='GC7CYPA', description='Maryland Ave.: The 50 States Project by UrbanAdventureSquad (2,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.89215, -76.988133, name='GC9EKPE', description='17 years underground by urbnX (2/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.93015, -77.028083,  name='GC34NZ3', description='DC Hidden Murals #2: Wonderland by exmachina (2/1)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.883071, -76.979078,  name='GC98F36', description='What’s Next? by alexcran421 (2/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.917767, -77.0159, name='GC43T1F', description='DC Hidden Murals #22: How We Live by exmachina (2/1)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.880617, -76.979417,  name='GC23GKB', description='SSB - Congressional Cemetery by Star-Spangled Banner (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.879183, -76.979733, name='GC6RNVG', description="Bonaparte's Cache by puglisimclare (1,5/1,5)"),
        GPXWaypoint(38.905583, -77.007567,  name='GC89MWE', description='DC Hidden Murals #31: AVA NoMa by exmachina (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.89367, -76.99609,  name='GC9XBFP', description='Hais Market by NatsGeo6 (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.889717, -76.996217,  name='GC9RQEP', description='16th and 44th by DCSunshine11 (1,5/1,5)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.918983, -77.028,  name='GC37CJT', description='DC Hidden Murals #7: Scout by exmachina (2/1)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.924896, -77.034439,  name='GC8ZXCP', description='Olive’s pipe by CharlesGeo8, Olive (1,5/1)'),
        GPXWaypoint(38.917467, -77.026933,  name='GC3VVZF', description='DC Hidden Murals #18: Bohemian Caverns by exmachina (2/1,5)'),   
         ]
    waypoints.insert(0, START_LOCATION)
    return waypoints

def create2dDistanceMatrix(locations:List[GPXWaypoint]):
    """Creates a distance matrix for the locations"""
    distance_matrix = []
    for i, location in enumerate(locations):
        distance_matrix.append([])
        for j, location_2 in enumerate(locations):
            distance_matrix[i].append(location.distance_2d(location_2))
    return distance_matrix

def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['num_vehicles'] = 1
    data['depot'] = 0
    data['vehicle_capacities'] = [5]
    print("Using 2d distances.")
    locations = [point for point in readGpxData() if point.name[:2] == "GC"]
    data["distance_matrix"] = create2dDistanceMatrix(locations)
    # Convert all distances to integers
    data["distance_matrix"] = [[int(i) for i in row] for row in data["distance_matrix"]]
    data['demands'] = [1]*len(data["distance_matrix"])
    return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment):
    """Prints assignment on console."""
    total_distance = 0
    total_load = 0
    locations = readGpxData()
    stations = []
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        route_load = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
            route_load += data['demands'][node_index]
            plan_output += ' {0} -> '.format(locations[node_index].name)
            stations.append(locations[node_index])
            previous_index = index
            index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        plan_output += ' {0} \n'.format(readGpxData()[data["depot"]].name)
        stations.append(readGpxData()[data["depot"]])
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
        print(plan_output)
        total_distance += route_distance
        total_load += route_load
    print('Total distance of all routes: {}m'.format(total_distance))
    createOutputGpxRouteFile(stations)

def main():
    """Entry point of the program."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
        demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')

    penalty = 999999999
    for node in range(1, len(data['distance_matrix'])):
        routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node)], penalty)

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(1)


    # Solve the problem.
    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if assignment:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Distances should be integral.

Comment: Are you talking of integers or do you mean integral as in adding each one to the one before? @LaurentPerron

Comment: the solver only accepts integer values. Any float will be silently converted by python to the nearest integer.

Comment: Ahh thank you. Still the same output tho. @LaurentPerron

Comment: as expected, but it is to prevent future error.

Answer (score 0):

In general heuristics can produce sub-optimal solutions (in your case tours), which might look "strange" when visualized, but which are perfectly valid.

However, you should check whether your visualization is representing the solution correctly, since your input data does not contain node coordiates but only the distances between them so that the positions are only relative to each other.

Your visualization should at least contain the node number / node coordinates of each node and the distance of each edge to aid you in inspecting your solution.

Comment: I just checked and the visualization is representing the solution.

Comment: And how can you be sure about that? The edges do not match the road network and the nodes still do not have a number / coordinate for representation.

Comment: I came to that conclusion because the point which I set as starting point (the depot) is at the right coordinates with the right name at the first place in the generated gpx. If the conversion from node to Waypoint would be wrong, the first waypoint in the gpx file wouldn't be the depot.

Comment: Still, i would not plot the "abstract" graph on the road network map. The distances used for the optimization procedure are probably a result of some kind of shortest path precalculation. In order to have a meaningful visualization on a road network you need to "unpack" the abstract edges of your graph to street level edges selected by the shortesdt path procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the guided local search please add:

```py
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(1)
    # search_parameters.log_search = True # enable solution log
```

Comment: I added it, however it doesn't change anything in the examples.

Answer (score -1):

This could be caused by the data. Your example does not provide enough information.

Please replace the code that queries `OpenRouteService`, also please provide a fixed vehicule capacity, and not rely on `input()`.

Comment: I have now edited the code so it's 100% reproducible, including your suggestions.

Comment: you could have used the generated distance matrix, instead of relying on gpx.

Comment: I decided not to use the distance matrix generated by OpenRouteService until I am certain that my code functions as intended because when visualising the result it looks even more strange because the shortest distance through the air isn't the same as the shortest distance through the road network